# Error loading PDF using react-pdf from web api 2, but not from file system

Tags: c#, reactjs, http, pdf, asp.net-web-api2

When I load a pdf from the file system via IIS, react-pdf renders the pdf without an issue. When I try to load it from a web service, however, react-pdf fails and throws an error. If I hit the service url directly in the browser, I can see the PDF.

React-pdf throws the following error:

```
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "104" in hex string
[Multiple warnings about invalid characters]
pdf.worker.js:349 
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects index.js:2178 
Invalid PDF structure InvalidPDFException {name:     "InvalidPDFException", message: "Invalid PDF structure"}
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
consoleOnDev @ utils.js:172
errorOnDev @ utils.js:189
Document._this.onLoadError @ Document.js:142
Promise.catch (async)
Document._this.onSourceSuccess @ Document.js:119
Promise.then (async)
loadDocument @ Document.js:314
componentDidMount @ Document.js:231
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:8770
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:9946
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10050
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11017
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11086
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2330
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3421
```

When I compare the http requests via fiddler, the response looks almost the same:

Loading pdf directly from file system:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 13:08:34 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "abc7c8a5fc7d31:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 14:31:16 GMT
Content-Length: 118306
```

Api call:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/pdf
Expires: -1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 13:14:54 GMT
```

The content looks the same in fiddler as well. Compared via winmerge. What else could be different? File encoding?

Using react-pdf 3.0.2

```
return (
        <div>
            <div className={this.state.className}></div>
            <Document file={link} onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoad} loading="">
                <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
            </Document>
            <p>Page {pageNumber} of {this.state.numPages}</p>
        </div>);
```

Comment: Hard to tell without the body of the response. Is the `Content-Length` the same? My guess would be that the file encoding is probably getting in your way.